# Assembly Binding Error: Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that contains a class library (ProjectA) and two Sharepoint projects (ProjectB & ProjectC). The dependency order is ProjectB references ProejctA and ProjectC references both ProjectA & ProjectB.

On one particular development machine i get the following error when trying to build ProjectC:

> Compilation failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

When looking into the fusion log i noted the following error:

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (14/06/2012 @ 09:38:32) ***
>
> The operation failed.
>
> Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>
> Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>
> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: User = DOMAIN\username
>
> LOG: DisplayName = ProjectB, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>    (Fully-specified)
>
> LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/
>
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
>
> LOG: Cache Base = NULL
>
> LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
>
> Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>
> LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config
>
> LOG: Using host configuration file:
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Post-policy reference: ProjectB, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/Editor/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/Editor/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ProjectB/ProjectB.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/Editor/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/Editor/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ProjectB/ProjectB.EXE.
>   LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

I have tried:

1. Removing the reference to ProjectB and re-adding it both:

   - a) as a project reference
   - b) as a manual reference directly to the debug folder of projectB
2. Manually placing the ProjectB.dll into the GAC
3. Changing the "Copy Local" option from True to False (and back to True)

And only (2) placing the assembly in the GAC allows ProjectC to build.
Why is it not finding the assembly as it should (and does on other machines)?

Comment: Are all of the machines 64bit or just this one?

Comment: All are 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out the reason the assembly could not be found was because we are [Delayed Signing the Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t07a3dye.aspx) this means that:

> Because the assembly does not have a valid strong name signature, the verification of that signature must be turned off. You can do this by using the –Vr option with the Strong Name tool.

I had already done this for all required public keys however ONLY in the x64 Visual Studio command prompt. I also needed to add the verification skipping for x86 in the x86 version of the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

I only managed to find this because trying a specific command based build/deployment script i noted the following exception with one of the test assemblies:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectC.Tests, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e72f8d3506b83180' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8013141A)

Answer (score 6):

PublicKeyToken=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa can be different or might be the version number of assembly is different. I think you should use  [Fusion Log Viewer to Debug](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) as described and hope fully you will solve your problem.

Comment: a) Fusion Log is above what i can understand from it is that it checks the GAC and then for some reason the IDE folders instead of the project bin folders. (b) As mentioned above if I manually put the ProjectB assembly in the GAC it is found (which implies the key is correct) - I have just manually checked (sn -T) and the key is the same.

Comment: can you paste the key which you have checked using (sn-T) and also the version number of assembly.

Comment: So i've removed the ProjectB dll from GAC and tried to build again i get the following in fusion: === Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = DOMAIN\username
LOG: DisplayName = ProjectB, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e72f8d3506b83180, processorArchitecture=MSIL
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/
...
...
LOG: Post-policy reference: ProjectB, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e72f8d3506b83180, processorArchitecture=MSIL
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.

Comment: Going into the bin/debug folder of ProjectB and running sn -T i get: "Public key token is e72f8d3506b83180" (Right-click properties of the dll shows version 0.0.0.0). After placing this assembly directly from the bin folder into the GAC I can build ProjectC without the error.

Comment: This is no use for me because the reference that isn't found is a project reference that is just built! It makes literally no sense that the file needs to be in the GAC. There has to be a better explanation for why the search paths are gimped.