# Windows Service Installation Error: Error 1001, Unable to get installer types assembly in the C:\Program Files\..\..\xxx.dll assembly.

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-services, windows-installer, installation

We're pushing a legacy Windows Service that was originally written for Windows 2003 to a Windows 2012 R2 Server for testing, however when we attempt to run the installer .msi, we are receiving the following error:

```
Error 1001, Unable to get installer types assembly in the C:\Program   Files\..\..\xxx.dll assembly. -> . Unable to load one or more of the requested   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

It appears that it may be an issue with an Oracle.DataAccess DLL:

[image: Oracle Error]

The Log Viewer provided this information:

```
    *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/22/2016 @ 1:54:54 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\syswow64\MsiExec.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MsiExec.exe
Calling assembly : CTMSRenewalOutboundService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Temp\CFG4155.tmp
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\PPD\CTMSOutboundService\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
ERR: Invalid assembly platform or ContentType in file (hr = 0x8007000b).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x8007000b.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/22/2016 @ 1:54:54 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\syswow64\MsiExec.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MsiExec.exe
Calling assembly : CTMSRenewalOutboundService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Temp\CFG4155.tmp
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\PPD\CTMSOutboundService\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
ERR: Invalid assembly platform or ContentType in file (hr = 0x8007000b).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x8007000b.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/22/2016 @ 4:01:10 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\syswow64\MsiExec.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MsiExec.exe
Calling assembly : CTMSRenewalOutboundService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Temp\CFGDA59.tmp
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\PPD\CTMSOutboundService\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
ERR: Invalid assembly platform or ContentType in file (hr = 0x8007000b).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x8007000b.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/22/2016 @ 4:01:10 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\syswow64\MsiExec.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MsiExec.exe
Calling assembly : CTMSRenewalOutboundService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Temp\CFGDA59.tmp
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\PPD\CTMSOutboundService\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
ERR: Invalid assembly platform or ContentType in file (hr = 0x8007000b).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x8007000b.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/PPD/CTMSOutboundService/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

I made sure to try both:

1. Copying a local copy of Oracle.DataAccess.DLL
2. Using a reference to the GAC for Oracle.DataAccess.DLL

However neither seemed to work.

We have deployed several other Windows Services that refer to this DLL, and had no issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1648302/5794617) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/2006795.aspx?Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+file+or+one+of+its+dependencies+The+system+cannot+find+the+file+specified) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030500/assembly-binding-error-bind-result-hr-0x80070002-the-system-cannot-find-the) ?

Answer (score 1):

It'll very likely be a bitness issue as those links imply. I'm going to add some extra info here.

The installer class in the installer assembly is not called directly. There is a C++ Dll that your MSI calls first, and this loads a version of the NET Runtime and then instantiates your custom action installer class methods through reflection (which is why you don't see your assembly load in FusionViewer). Copy Local won't matter during the install - it will load GAC assemblies. Apart from being instantiated via reflection, your CA assembly is being called from an msiexec.exe process and won't load any config or settings files you have, or otherwise care where it's running from (for examplr there is no working directory of the assembly's location).

The chain of bitness gets complicated - your setup may be x86 or x64, your custom action Dll may be x86, x64 or AnyCpu. It will try to load dependencies which may not match. If it's an x86 install, build your installer class for x86 and make sure anything it calls is built for x86. Same idea if it's x64. So a possible explanation is that Server 2012 is 64-bit and your CA assembly is running native and looking for 32-bit Oracle assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Our workaround to this issue after speaking with Microsoft Support was to use Orca to override the InstallUtilLib.dll being referenced in the 32 bit .Net framework directory.

By using Orca, we were able to point the msi to the c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64 directory.

1. Open the resulting .msi in Orca from the Windows Installer SDK
2. Select the Binary table
3. Double click the cell [Binary Data] for the record InstallUtil
4. Make sure “Read binary from filename” is selected and click the Browse button
5. Browse to %WINDIR%Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
6. Select InstallUtilLib.dll
7. Click the Open button
8. Click the OK button

As soon as we followed these steps, we were able to install the Windows Service.

We had several other Windows Services that we built and upgraded to Windows 2012R2 without any issues.  For some reason this was the only service that required this workaround.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks.